# C# foreach with string - ignore last character

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a methode who add numbers together parsed from a string.

If user type : "52+7+1", it will result in (60)
"52++2+3", "52+c+2", "+52+2", "52+2++", ... won't work.

My code works almost perfectly, expect... it ignores the last character. It works when, in the code I add "+0" to the string but of course it brokes the condition who prevent the user to type "+" as a last character.

```
    public int addFromString(string str)
    {
        bool valid_str = true;
        bool current_char_numeric = false;

        string unparsedNumber = "";
        int parsedNumber = 0;
        List<int> parsedNumbers = new List<int>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chaine))
            chaine_valide = false;
        else
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(str[0].ToString(), out parsedNumber))
               valid_str = false;

            if (!int.TryParse(str[str.Length - 1].ToString(), out parsedNumber))
                valid_str = false;
        }

        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            current_char_numeric = int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out parsedNumber);

            if (current_char_numeric)
                unparsedNumber += c;
            else if(c == '+')
            {
                int.TryParse(unparsedNumber, out parsedNumber);
                parsedNumbers.Add(parsedNumber);

                if (str.IndexOf(c) < str.Length && str.ElementAt(str.IndexOf(c) + 1) == '+')
                    valid_str = false;

                //Just in case :
                unparsedNumber = "";
                current_char_numeric = int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out parsedNumber);
            }
            else valid_str = false;
        }

        int result = 0;

        if(valid_str) { foreach(int n in parsedNumbers) { result += n; } }

        return result;
}
```

So if I type : "52+2" I get 52

If I type : "52+2+6" I get 54

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're attempting here. If all you want to do is add valid integers separated by a plus symbol, this code is excessive. Can you also clarify what you mean regarding the last character?

Comment: Agreed with Dan, a much simpler approach would be to split your string on '+' and sum the resulting array instead.

Comment: `foreach (char c in str)` does *not* ignore the last character. Either the input string does *not* contain the characters you thought it did, or there is a bug in the code. `foreach` isn't broken

Comment: `var result = string.Split('+').Select(value => int.Parse(value)).Sum();`

Comment: If you want to create a parser, create *different* methods for different tokens and rules. As it is, it's very hard to understand what that single method does, where you recognize numbers vs operands and where you perform the calculations. Each of these should be a different method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He doesn't say `foreach` is broken, he says *his code* is broken.

Comment: @Rawling not according to the title. It's clear the OP thinks there's something wrong with `foreach`

Comment: I didn't knew about that Split function at all ! Is there a way with that method to check if there is no "++" or no other characters than numbers/+ ?

Comment: Btw, I cannot create a single method, I'm doing an exercise and it implies that I put the code in one method.

Comment: @SanchezTanguy once you have the tokens you can check them yourself. Double `++` will result in empty strings in the array

Comment: @SanchezTanguy write the code with multiple methods to get it right, then merge them again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It misses the last value because you only add numbers if you find a `+`. So for the last `unparsedNumber` you never enter the `else if (c == '+')` block.

Let me suggest an more compact solution:

```
public int addFromString(string str)
{
    string trimmed = str.Trim();
    if (str.StartsWith("+") || str.EndsWith("+")) return 0; // invalid -> return immediatly

    // split string at "+" and trim parts
    string[] numbers = str.Split('+').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
    int result = 0;
    foreach(string number in numbers)
    {
        int n;
        if (!int.TryParse(number, out n)) return 0; // invalid -> return
        result += n;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: So much more compact than my version !
I'm too used to C++. C# string are so powerfull I'm surprised. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I found this to check that the string start with a number : `if (!Char.IsDigit(str[0]) && !Char.IsDigit(str[str.Length - 1])) return 0;`

Comment: It would be better to return `int?` so that the error value can be `null`. The current code cannot distinguish between the correct result of `"0+0"` and an error. But, then again, that's what the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

You only add a number to the numbers collection when you encounter a `+`.
What about the last number? There's no '+' after that.

You should add `unparsedNumber` to `parsedNumbers` for the last number too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a more elegant version:

```
public int addFromString(string str)
{
        int parsedNumber = 0;            
        int result = 0;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chaine))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(str[0].ToString(), out parsedNumber)
                 || !int.TryParse(str[str.Length - 1].ToString(), out parsedNumber))
            {
                 return result;
            }
        }

        try
        {
             result = str.Split(new char[] { '+' }).Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).Sum();
        }
        finally
        {
             return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: It does not check if the user inputed wrong values in-between ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you want is `Split`:

```
  string source = "52+7+1";

  int sum = 0;                // initial sum is 0
  bool chaine_valide = true;  // the chain is valid (we don't have any counter examples)

  // Split on terms: 52, 7, 1
  foreach (string term in source.Split('+')) {
    int value;

    // No need in Trim() etc. - TryParse is smart enough
    if (int.TryParse(term, out value))
      sum += value;          // valid term: add it up
    else {
      chaine_valide = false; // counter example: term is not a valid integer

      break;
    }
  }

  ...

  Console.Write(chaine_valide ? sum.ToString() : "Invalid formula");
```

In case of **C# 7.0** you can (with a help of `out var`) simplify the code into

```
  int sum = 0;                // initial sum is 0
  bool chaine_valide = true;  // the chain is valid (we don't have any counter examples)

  // Split on terms: 52, 7, 1
  foreach (string term in source.Split('+')) 
    if (int.TryParse(term, out var value))
      sum += value;          // valid term: add it up
    else {
      chaine_valide = false; // counter example: term is not a valid integer

      break;
    }
```